# How to fix MDT Failure 5624 : 14 Dism.exe

Tags: deployment, hyper-v, winpe, mdt

When deploying a image to Hyper-V VM's using the latest MDT & Windows ADK installations, the imaging process will fail with the first line of errors being:

```
FAILURE (5627): 14: Rum DISM.exe

Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = – 2147467259 0x80004005
```

Like many who experience this issue, I assumed the source of the error was with the configuration of MDT. As such, i tried - in vain - everything from simply modifying settings in the workbench and task sequence, to fully re-installing the MDT workbench and Windows ADK. This included replacing whole images, too.

None of this worked, and the same error persisted whenever i tried to deploy an image using MDT to a Hyper-V VM.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was "insufficient Resources" as in screenshot below.

Increasing the VM RAM to 2 GB and deployment went smooth..

Also here>>> https://www.osd-couture.com/2016/02/mdt-2013u1u2-failure-5627-run-dismexe.html